# CFcookie acting weird in various browsers

Tags: javascript, cookies, coldfusion

So the following code works perfectly in Firefox

```
<!--Cookies-->
<cfset timer = createTimeSpan(0,3,0,0)>
<cfcookie name = "user.ID" value = "#userID#" expires="#timer#">               <!--this will expire in three hours -->
<cfcookie name = "user.Site" value = "#userSite#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.Sess" value = "#userSess#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.FName" value = "#userFName#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.LName" value = "#userLName#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.Email" value = "#userEmail#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.SiteFirst" value = "#userSiteFirst#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.RoundsTotal" value = "#userRoundsTotal#" expires="#timer#">
<cfcookie name = "user.RoundsCurrent" value = "#userRoundsCurrent#" expires="#timer#">

<!-- And now we send the user off to wait.cfm where they will wait --->
<!-- Users will not head to choose their picture choice --->

<script type="text/javascript">
    location.href='picChoice.cfm';
</script>
```

In Firefox, the values within all the cookies are passed perfectly. Any other browser, and all the cookies are null.

Hoping someone can see something wrong where I cannot. If you want to look at the full cfm, you can do so here : http://pastebin.com/4G4wvjLd

Comment: That's a lot of cookies. Have you thought of using localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a load problem - where the browser is redirected prior to finalizing the cookie operation. Change your location.href to a cflocation or put it in the body "onLoad()" event (or use jquery's load event to handle browser redirect nuances).

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok to me. I've run it here, using the cookie name as the cookie value e.g.  and the cookies are correctly set and passed OK in IE and Chrome.
there are some holes in the Cookie spec (written by Netscape back in the day) which leads to some browsers doing slightly different things in certain situations. 
I'd recommend 2 things:

1) Simplify the values being sent. In my case, I'm using the cookie name as the cookie value and it seems to work. I'd do the same as a test and just cfdump #cookie# in picChoice.cfm (that's what I did in my test page here)

2) run the requests using fiddler as a proxy and watch what the browser is getting and sending, just to make sure that your code really is sending the set-cookie headers and to see what the browser is sending back to the server.